# tidyr::unite drops decimal 0

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to combine numbers from two and two columns within a data frame (values in the columns are the upper and lower values for confidence intervals in statistical analysis).

My perferred method would be to use `tidyr` and the `unite` function. But take 0.20 as an example, that number will be modified to 0.2, i.e. these last decimals in numbers are dropped if they are equal to zero. Is there any way to keep the original format when using `unite`?

`unite` is describe here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.2/topics/unite

Example:

```
# Dataframe
df <-  structure(list(est = c(0.05, -0.16, -0.02, 0, -0.11, 0.15, -0.26, 
-0.23), low2.5 = c(0.01, -0.2, -0.05, -0.03, -0.2, 0.1, -0.3, 
-0.28), up2.5 = c(0.09, -0.12, 0, 0.04, -0.01, 0.2, -0.22, -0.17
)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Combining (uniting) columns for confidence with `unite`, using a comma as a separator

```
library(tidyr)
df <- unite(df, "CI", c("low2.5", "up2.5"), sep = ", ", remove=T)
```

gives

```
df
    est           CI
1  0.05   0.01, 0.09
2 -0.16  -0.2, -0.12
3 -0.02     -0.05, 0
4  0.00  -0.03, 0.04
5 -0.11  -0.2, -0.01
6  0.15     0.1, 0.2
7 -0.26  -0.3, -0.22
8 -0.23 -0.28, -0.17
```

I would want this:

```
    est           CI
1  0.05   0.01, 0.09
2 -0.16  -0.20, -0.12
3 -0.02  -0.05, 0.00
4  0.00  -0.03, 0.04
5 -0.11  -0.20, -0.01
6  0.15   0.10, 0.20
7 -0.26  -0.30, -0.22
8 -0.23  -0.28, -0.17
```

I believing doing this with Base R will be complicated (having to move/rearrange the many combined columns and delete the old columns). Is there any way to avoid `unite` from dropping decimals with the value of zero?

Comment: `format` or `sprintf` before you `unite`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~format(., nsmall = 2)) %>% 
  unite("CI", c("low2.5", "up2.5"), sep = ", ", remove=T)
#    est           CI
#1  0.05  0.01,  0.09
#2 -0.16 -0.20, -0.12
#3 -0.02 -0.05,  0.00
#4  0.00 -0.03,  0.04
#5 -0.11 -0.20, -0.01
#6  0.15  0.10,  0.20
#7 -0.26 -0.30, -0.22
#8 -0.23 -0.28, -0.17
```

Comment: Problem solved, even with nicely aligned text in the new column! Thanks a lot.